# string argv[] redefinition error C++

Tags: c++, string, constructor, argv, redefinition

I came across to redefinition error when pass string(argv[]) to class constructor as argument. The sample codes are as follows. cA1 produced redefinition error but all cA2, cA3, cA4, and func are fine. Could anyone help me on it?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(string String1, string String2);
    ~A();

};

void func(string String1, string String2)
{

}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //error C2086: 'std::string argv[]' : redefinition
    A cA1(string(argv[1]), string(argv[2]));

    string String1 = string(argv[1]);
    string String2 = string(argv[2]);
    //fine 
    A cA2(String1, String2);

    //fine 
    A cA3(argv[1], argv[2]);

    //fine
    A cA4(string(argv[1]).c_str(), string(argv[2]).c_str());

    //fine
    func(string(argv[1]), string(argv[2]));
}
```

Comment: You should include your error output as well.

Comment: @robert I put the error output on the comments

Answer (score 3):

`A cA1(string(argv[1]), string(argv[2]));` doesn't call your constructor, however, it declares a function name *`cA1`*<sub>[*'Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?'*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/1870232)</sub>, with parameters 
`string(argv[1])` and `string(argv[2])` both having same argument variable name `argv`, hence the error